# Go network programming libs

Tags: networking, go

I've decided to rewrite most of my distributed server programs in Go to replace the existing c# based ones.

Can someone point me to a Go TCP libs or a Go general network programming lib.

Thanks

Edi: ... and how do i complile this code is visual stuido 2008? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the official API docs for the [net package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/).

Regarding how to compile: See the [installation guide](http://golang.org/doc/install.html). As of yet there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to compile in VS:

> The Go tool chain is written in C. To
>   build it, you need to have GCC, the
>   standard C libraries, the parser
>   generator Bison, and the text editor
>   ed installed.

So in order to develop on Windows, the easiest route would be to use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: And even this won't get you there, as the resulting output won't be a PE executable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the needs of your distributed software, you may also want to check out the [rpc package](http://golang.org/pkg/rpc/) which makes it quite easy to register an object's public methods and call them remotely.